# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_column'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting that error and have already checked the forums & have found no answer as I do have the correct imports installed. Here is my current import list:

```
import xlwings as xw 
import xlsxwriter as xlsx
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy 
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np 
import datetime
import os.path   
import warnings
```

Here's the code I'm getting errors on:

```
wb = xlsx.Workbook(File_path)
ws = ws 

ws.set_column('A:A', 60)
```

ws comes form:

```
ws = wb.get_worksheet_by_name('Data')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In `ws = ws`: where does the right-hand `ws` come from?

Comment: ws = wb.sheets['Data']

Comment: What version of XlsxWriter are you using? The `wb.sheets` attribute doesn't exist in `XlsxWriter==3.0.3`.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.3, will look for the correct attributes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
ws = wb.sheets['Data']
```

with

```
ws = wb.get_worksheet_by_name('Data')
```

Comment: Now I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_column'` and when trying to get column headers to bold, I get the same error.

Comment: @JoseDanielRojas - not sure why ws would be none in this instance. Are you sure the variable isn't getting overwritten somewhere? If the sheet name is incorrect it should throw an exception. Your ws=ws line of code makes me nervous!

Comment: So, my logic is: I get the information I need, paste it on an existing excel document, and then I edit said excel's document column headers to bold, and column widths. I am getting the information I want on the excel document and all the columns have names. 

After that is done via: `app = xw.App(visible = False)`, `wb = xw.Book(File_path)`, `ws = wb.sheets['Data']` & `ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df` I save, close and quit the excel app. 

After that I:
`wb = xlsx.Workbook(File_path)`,`ws = wb.get_worksheet_by_name('Data')` & `ws.set_column('A:A', 60)`